# How can i add object array of items to listView same as i'm adding them to listBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is how I'm adding the item to the listBox:

```
this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray());
```

And this is how I'm trying to add them to the listView:

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray());
```

This is the listView control code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MinimizeCapture
{
    public partial class ListViewCostumControl : UserControl
    {
        public static ListViewControl lvnf;

        public ListViewCostumControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lvnf = new ListViewControl();
            lvnf.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            lvnf.Size = new Size(50, 50);
            lvnf.View = View.SmallIcon;
            lvnf.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            lvnf.SuspendLayout();
            lvnf.LabelEdit = true;
            lvnf.Sorting = SortOrder.None;
            this.Controls.Add(lvnf);
            lvnf.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        public class ListViewControl : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
        {
            public ListViewControl()
            {
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
                this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage, true);
            }

            protected override void OnNotifyMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                if (m.Msg != 0x14)
                {
                    base.OnNotifyMessage(m);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ListViewNFTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The errors I'm getting when trying to add the items to the listView are:

```
Error   14  The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection.AddRange(System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection)' has some invalid arguments

Error   15  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MinimizeCapture.WindowSnap[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection'
```

This is the GetAllWindows method:

```
public static WindowSnapCollection GetAllWindows(bool minimized, bool specialCapturring)
        {
            windowSnaps = new WindowSnapCollection();
            countMinimizedWindows = minimized;//set minimized flag capture
            useSpecialCapturing = specialCapturring;//set specialcapturing flag
            EnumWindowsCallbackHandler callback = new EnumWindowsCallbackHandler(EnumWindowsCallback);
            EnumWindows(callback, IntPtr.Zero);
            return new WindowSnapCollection(windowSnaps.ToArray(), true);
        }
```

And this is the WindowSnapCollection:

```
public WindowSnapCollection(WindowSnap[] items, bool asReadOnly)
        {
            base.AddRange(items);
            base.TrimExcess();
            this.asReadonly = asReadOnly;
        }
```

WindowSnap is the name os the class with the GetAllWindow method.

Is this example I did now is a good solution?
I added it to the listView control code at the top:

```
Object myObj = new Object();
ListViewItem[] items = new ListViewItem[8];
```

Then in constructor:

```
items[0].Text = myObj.ToString();
items[0].Tag = myObj;
lvnf.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Do I need the tag?
How do I use it instead of making an instance of 8 items?

Comment: Try ToList instead of ToArray

Comment: There is no a property ToList only ToArray and ToString

Answer (score 3):

The problem is what you are trying to add, that is what

```
WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray()
```

is returning as an argument.

The listbox AddRange parameter accepts two different arguments;

```
AddRange(Object[])
AddRange(ListBox.ObjectCollection)
```

So the first accepts any array of objects, and this is what you are using.

ListView however is not as flexible.  It accepts;

```
AddRange(ListViewItem[])
AddRange(ListView.ListViewItemCollection)
```

Therefore, you cannot send an array of objects as you can with listbox.  You have to be more specific in the type of data you pass to it.
I would suggest that you create some kind of wrapper around it to change the format of the data you want into the expected input format.

Comment: probably write an extension method ToListViewItem which converts array of object to Array of ListViewItem

Comment: Can't figure out yet how to do it. Could someone please how how to do it ? Thank you.